# Edit certificate chain in Java keystore

Tags: java, keystore, chain, ca

I have a certificate for a Glassfish server within a Java keystore. It has a 4part certificate chain, which I can see with the `list` command. Now one of the intermediate CA certificates has been revoked and I have to change the chain of my certificate, because it is now untrusted.

In the Windows IIS I have added the new intermediate certificate to the certificate store and all was fine. For the Java keystore I have no idea how I could do that? Should I export the certificate incl. the chain as PEM and replace the text parts for the intermediate CA? The CA says, I don't have to use a new certificate, it is only necessary to correct the chain, so it makes no sense to generate a new certificate request.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for instructions on how to use keytool?  If that's the case, have a look here http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html .

Comment: Yes, I know this page. But the problem is not to import the intermediate certificates into the keystore. The problem is, that I have a PrivateKeyEntry within the keystore, which contains a certificate chain with 4 certificates (long time ago I created a CSR from the keystore and imported the response from the CA). Two of the chain certificates I have to redirect to other certificates. So I think, the import of the new certificates will not change the references within the chain. Should I export the private key to another keystore without chain and import the new intermediate certs there???

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31441070/394431