# How to remove just one certificate from a certificate chain in a Java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, keystore

I have a Tomcat server with a certificate chain for HTTPS stored in a Java keystore.  The chain includes the self-signed root CA certificate.  Although this is apparently okay by [the TLS spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), some validation services warn about it, and [it's probably better to leave it off](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65332/ssl-root-certificate-optional).

How can I edit the keystore to remove just the self-signed root CA certificate, but leave the rest of the chain and the private key intact?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, convert the keystore from JKS to PKCS12 (this and other commands will require password entry):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore old.jks -destkeystore old.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Next, export a PEM file with key and certs from the PKCS12 file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in old.p12 -out pemfile.pem -nodes
```

Now simply use a text editor to edit `pemfile.pem` and remove the offending certificate (and its preceding "Bag Attributes").

Next, load the edited PEM file into a new PKCS12 file.  You'll need to give the cert/key the appropriate keystore alias, e.g. "tomcat", at this point.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in pemfile.pem -name tomcat -out new.p12
```

Finally, convert back from PKCS12 to JKS:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore new.p12 -destkeystore new.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

The file `new.jks` is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

keytool -delete -alias -keystore lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

Comment: Can you explain the parms a bit; is `changeit` the certificate to delete?

Comment: `changeit` is the default password for Java keystores